# How to launch a web page on opening of the application

Tags: cocoa

Hello everyone i need some help. I'm trying to make an application for mac in Xcode 4.0 and i want it to display a webpage on launch i have already added the webkit framework and have got some code but its not working. the code is below

The app delegate.m file

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;


@synthesize WebView;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[WebView mainFrame] LoadRequest:requestObj];
}

@end
```

and the app delegate.h file

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

 #import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@property (assign) IBOutlet WebView *WebView;

@interface myAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    WebView *myWebView;

}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet WebView *myWebView;

@end
```

If anyone can help please respond asap thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm, i'm assuming that code isn't compiling? (it shouldn't be! :) ). the .h should look something like:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    WebView *_myWebView; // not needed if you're using the latest xcode
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet WebView *myWebView;

@end
```

and the .m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize myWebView = _myWebView;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[self.myWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:requestObj]; // note the lower case 'l' in 'loadRequest'
}

@end
```

this assumes you've connected the webview in the .xib with the myWebView property.

Comment: Thanks man that fixed it up another reason was also i forgot to connect the web view with the mywebview property